# Ошибка Mysql при переходt на php 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

В общем ситуация такая, на PHP до 7 версии этот запрос работает.

```
$db->query('SELECT name, parent_id FROM '.PREFIX.'_people WHERE cid = '.mysql_escape_string($_GET['cid']));
```

Но в PHP 7+ он выдает ошибку, хотя я меняю на MySQLi вот так

```
$db->query('SELECT name, parent_id FROM '.PREFIX.'_people WHERE cid = '.mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']));
```

Собственно вот такую мне ошибку и выдает:

> The Error returned was: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

Уже всю голову сломал, не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: Скопируйте финальную строку, которая получается для передачи функции query в вопрос.

Comment: SQL query:

SELECT name, parent_id FROM tbl_people WHERE cid =

Comment: Неудивительно, что вы получаете ошибку - у вас нет последнего параметра. А уж почему - неизвестно. Вам придётся отладить и посмотреть что там происходит, либо воспользоваться var_dump или аналогичными способами.

Comment: Это я понимаю, я не могу понять почему последний параметр с GET не подхватывает. В php ниже 7 версии работает хорошо

Comment: Какой смысл экранировать `id` не приведя его к типу `integer`? Ну а так в `mysqli_real_escape_string` первым [параметром](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-parameters) соединение нужно передавать.

Comment: пример можно наглядный

Answer (score 5):

> WHERE cid = '.mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']));

Вы где и зачем потеряли `PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`? Вам PHP прямым текстом отвечает в чём ошибка. Почему вы его не слышите?

[`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) в процедурном стиле вызова требует передачу объекта `mysqli`. Потому что информация о кодировке соединения требуется для корректного выполнения экранирования.

Почему вы не видите предупреждение языка - проверяйте свой `error_reporting`, `display_errors`. Во время разработки они обязаны быть включены и ваш код не должен создавать даже ошибки уровня `E_NOTICE`.

Ну а некорректно вызванный `mysqli_real_escape_string` возвращает `warning` и `NULL`. `NULL` при конкатенации приводится к пустой строке, что и выглядит как наблюдаемое поведение.

Comment: Ошибку я глянул, Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in единственное моих знаний не особо хватает. Можете мне показать пример как мне нужно запрос прописать

Comment: Вам нужно передать *два* параметра в функцию. Первым параметром объект подключения к базе, вторым строку которую надо экранировать. Может быть `mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['cid'])`. Может быть нет, я не знаю что такое `$db` у вас и где у вас переменная хранящая подключение к mysql.